# Rails routing using destroy action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

In my app, comments belong to photos and I am trying to add a method to destroy a comment.

**routes.rb**

```
resources :photos do        
  resources :comments
end
```

**CommentsController**

```
def destroy
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  @comment.destroy
end
```

**photos/show.html.erb**

```
<% @photo.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= comment.body %></p>
  <p><%= link_to 'Remove comment', comment, :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to remove this comment? This cannot be undone.', :method => :delete %></p>
<% end %>
```

The error I get is `undefined method 'comment' for #<Photo:0x10ace9270>`.

I think I may not have my routes setup correctly because when I check the routes for `comment` I get:

```
rake routes | grep comment
              photo_comments GET    /photos/:photo_id/comments(.:format)                              {:action=>"index", :controller=>"comments"}
                             POST   /photos/:photo_id/comments(.:format)                              {:action=>"create", :controller=>"comments"}
           new_photo_comment GET    /photos/:photo_id/comments/new(.:format)                          {:action=>"new", :controller=>"comments"}
          edit_photo_comment GET    /photos/:photo_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format)                     {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"comments"}
               photo_comment GET    /photos/:photo_id/comments/:id(.:format)                          {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments"}
                             PUT    /photos/:photo_id/comments/:id(.:format)                          {:action=>"update", :controller=>"comments"}
                             DELETE /photos/:photo_id/comments/:id(.:format)                          {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"comments"}
```

Anyone have thoughts as to where I went wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<% @photo.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= comment.body %></p>
  <p><%= link_to 'Remove comment', [@photo, comment], :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to remove this comment? This cannot be undone.', :method => :delete %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: bam! Yea, that did the trick. I guess my routes are ok then. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Its because he passed in @photo. Since the comments are nested under photos.